# orientdb spring data support IN operator doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-data, orientdb, findby, sql-in

i use orientdb-spring-data library in the repository layer of my application.
 I have a pojo named Application with an attribute named type. 
 I try to  execute the following query:

```
List<Application<?>> findByTypeIn(List<String> type);
```

But it doesn't work. The query that is constructed is the following:

```
select * from Application where type in ('[XPR,MS]')
```

this query is obviously wrong because it takes the whole list of types as an array entry inside  the parenthesis.

Can anyone help me which data structure should be provided to construct a query like this:

```
select * from Application where type in ('XPR', 'MS')
```

i also tried with @Query annotation and it had the same behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ilianna Spiliopoulou,  what version are you using? Have you tried to upgrade ?